# random date time generation using VB script

Tags: vbscript

how to generate date along with time randomly between a start date and end date using VB script. We have to take input from user 
Example: startDate:15/09/2013 9:00:00 Enddate 21/09/2013 15:00:00

Output : Random date :17/09/2013 12:00:00

Answer (score 4):

Add a random number of seconds less than the difference between the dates in seconds to the startDate:

```
  Dim StartDate : StartDate = #15/09/2013 9:00:00#
  Dim Enddate   : Enddate   = #21/09/2013 15:00:01#
  Dim SecDiff   : SecDiff   = DateDiff("s", StartDate, Enddate)
  WScript.Echo StartDate, Enddate, SecDiff
  Dim n
  For n = 1 To 20
      WScript.Echo DateAdd("s", Fix(SecDiff * Rnd()), StartDate)
  Next
```

output (german locale):

```
15.09.2013 09:00:00 21.09.2013 15:00:01 540001
19.09.2013 18:49:56
18.09.2013 17:00:49
18.09.2013 23:55:40
17.09.2013 04:26:04
17.09.2013 06:17:32
20.09.2013 05:12:40
...
```